# Web crawling using PHP

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I am writing a simple crawler that fetches links to articles from engadget.com and for each article i save the entire html document

```
    $target_url = "http://www.engadget.com/all/page/1/";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('script') as $script){
        if($script->type == "application/ld+json"){
            $json_data = strip_tags($script);
            if($content = json_decode($json_data)){
                $listElements = $content->itemListElement;
                foreach($listElements as $element){
                    echo "Running..";
                    $article_url = $element->url;
                    $article_page = new simple_html_dom();
                    try{                            
                        $article_page->load_file($article_url);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        sleep(20);
                        $article_page->load_file($article_url);
                    } finally {
                        $filename = "raw_file".$file_num.".txt";
                        $file = fopen("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\files\\".$filename,"w");
                        fwrite($file, $article_page);
                        fclose($file);
                        $file_num++;
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

Most of the times this works fine but sometimes a page fails to load and I get a 503 error. To solve this, currently I am suspending the execution for 20 seconds before retrying with the same url. This has significantly reduced the fail cases but still sometimes it fails in the second try as well.
Is there a better way to make sure that I get the data from the page. Is there a way to keep trying till the page responds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good idea to increase the interval dinamically everytime an exception occurs and try again, something like:

```
foreach ($listElements as $element) {
    echo "Running..";
    $article_url = $element->url;
    $article_page = new simple_html_dom();
    $interval = 0;
    $tries = 0;
    $success = false;

    while (!$suceess && $tries < 5) {
        try {
            sleep($interval);               
            $article_page->load_file($article_url);
            $success = true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $interval += 20;
            $tries ++;
            $article_page->load_file($article_url);
        } finally {
            $filename = "raw_file".$file_num.".txt";
            $file = fopen("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\files\\".$filename,"w");
            fwrite($file, $article_page);
            fclose($file);
            $file_num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the catch block was never getting invoked since the errors I am getting are PHP Warnings and not exceptions. So the second loadfile never gets executed. I now doubt if the try catch block will be any effective. Even after the failure success would get set to true and the loop will get terminated for the current url....any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of trying to catch an exception, I am now checking for the length of the string article_page (String because thats what load_file returns). If the length is 0 (in case of the error), I retry as suggested in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The website might have set up a request interval limitation to avoid data harvesting. For a reason... So, don't just copy someone else's site contents :)

Or if there is a API, use that to load/get the contents.

(Technically, you could let your site loop requests until it has a right response, using intervals and resetting time limits to avoid PHP from stopping.)

Comment: I could not find an API for the site....i'll try playing with the time interval as suggested by you and @Saul below